# Android APK name changed when changing device language?

Tags: android, apk, android-install-apk

I have faced strange behavior with my app when device language is **English** my app name is ok, but when I change the language to **Arabic** the APK and app name change to Awesome Image picker ? which is a lib I use in my app to choose multiple images !!

Manifest :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mtids.mat3ami">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".SignInUser" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name" />
        <activity android:name=".SignUpUser" />

        <activity android:name=".Search"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"/>
        <activity android:name=".SearchByName" />
        <activity android:name=".SearchByPrice"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

strings.xml :

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">Mat3ami</string>

    <string name="navigation_drawer_open">Open navigation drawer</string>
    <string name="navigation_drawer_close">Close navigation drawer</string>

    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>

    <string name="facebook_app_id">*********</string>



</resources>
```

Any ideas, help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you create different Strings file for different language ??

Comment: You must have added "app_name" string in Arabic values folder too. Right? Is this the resource file of Arabic folder?

Comment: simple solution is change the  `<string name="app_name">Mat3ami</string>` with  `<string name="app_name_math2ami">Mat3ami</string>` and use that res at all place so other resource can not overrite it

Comment: @SnehaSarkar  i didn't made any new resources files for Arabic language, i have only the main project string.xml

Comment: You need to add different resource files for different languages. Please go to this link and make necessary changes according to your requirements.https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html

Comment: @SnehaSarkar I know about supporting multiple languages in Android, and I have accomplished many apps without the need for it i'm just wondering the Awesome Image Picker name from where it came and why my app name changing to that name ?

Comment: add translatable= false to your app_name string. May be that can solve your issue. <string name="app_name" translatable="false">Mat3ami</string>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android has support to  [Different Languages and Cultures](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html) according to the device's language setup. You can achieve that working with different strings resource for which language that you desire to support

In your project, right-click res/values/ and select New -> Values resource file. Enter "strings" for the file name and leave the source option set to main. In the Available qualifiers and click ">>" button to move "Locale"to the Chosen qualifiers section. Select the language that you wish to support and select the region (default is: Any region) and left-click "Ok". Android studio will automatically generate a new resource file also called "strings.xml".

Now preserving the string's name from the original string resources, make your translations and you will be fine to internationalize your app :).

Comment: The only solution is to add new string.xml for Arabic language

Answer (score 2):

You have to override the Arabic resource file `value-ar/strings.xml`, and write the name you want inside it,

```
<string name="app_name">Mat3ami</string>
```

i think this case happened because one of the libraries that you are using is overriding the app_name.

Regards.